# How do I Sort the order (ascending) in List view for Last Modified Date?

Tags: community

I have one custom object and I have some list views with the custom object.There are some fields account number,name,created date,Last Modified Date and I want display the list of 'Last Modified Date' in ascending order or display the list of 'account number' in descending order in list view ??
    Does anybody have answer?

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. as is it is kind of hard to tell what you are asking. please update your post to contain further details, for example, what type of community (lightning?), a screenshot maybe? is this a custom component, if so, please include the relevant code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard Salesforce list view only gives the option to sort on one column at a time. All you would need to do for that is simply click the column header and it will change sorting.

[image: Created Date Sorting]
[image: Account Number sorting]

If you want to be able to do both - I would suggest replacing the standard list view with your own custom list tab layout.

1: Navigate to the Buttons, Links and Actions section for the object that you want to modify:

[image: Step 1 - navigate to object buttons and links]

2: Click Edit for the Tab item in this section:

[image: Step 2 - click edit for the Tab in Buttons and links]

3: Select the page layout that you create to override this tab's layout with:

[image: Step 3 - Override the tab with your own page and custom table]

There are many JQuery options or HTML Tables that you can create or even a lightning table that you can build that will allow multiple column sorting order.

Here is a [JQuery](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) example that you can work with and implement with your Salesforce Data

Here is a [Lightning](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/02/20/custom-sorting-lightning-component/) Data Table example that as well you can add some customization to and allow multiple column sorting if this is what you want to do. I hope this information was helpful in getting you along your way to a more functional UI for your implementation.